# Configuration in a dynamically loaded DLL

Tags: c#, .net, app-config, config, .net-assembly

I loaded a DLL through `Assembly.LoadFile`. Objects of a class, that is described in the DLL, need initial configuration prior to use but I can't add a `.config` file to a DLL.

Is there a way to load a DLL with a `.config` file or another method to set a configuration?
Any comments, please.

Comment: How do the dynamically loaded objects require configuration?  Do they make reference to `AppSetttings` or a `ConfigurationSection` directly, or do you build them with pre-loaded configuration values?

Comment: I need to set some parameters that usually is defined in `.config` file (f.e. ConnectionStrings) but I can't find out how to use `.config` in case of dynamic loading

Comment: Have you seen this?
http://myprogrammingexp.wordpress.com/2011/12/16/separate-config-files-for-dlls/